# DAX Subtotal Not Adding up

Tags: dax

I have tried to use the summarize function to get the subtotals but it does not add up. Can any help in fixing the formula.

[https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/11u-\_wQPggGqvrQdCWD3GHfCBSVAFpqIj?usp=sharing](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/11u-%5C_wQPggGqvrQdCWD3GHfCBSVAFpqIj?usp=sharing)

I tried using the summarize function but there is something i am doing wrong here.[image]

Comment: Check your link.

Comment: Please try below. thanks.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14eHHMxVZ7BHUWggNLqoflzsMGihKi59e/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=101506769886294531018&rtpof=true&sd=true